# How to compared two lists in python and return them in dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two lists:
names: `['Mary', 'Jack', 'Rose', 'Mary', 'Carl', 'Fred', 'Meg', 'Phil', 'Carl', 'Jack', 'Fred', 'Mary', 'Phil', 'Jack', 'Mary', 'Fred', 'Meg']`

grades: `[80, 88, 53, 80, 64, 61, 75, 80, 91, 82, 68, 76, 95, 58, 89, 51, 81, 78]`

I want to be able to take the average of each persons test scores. For example, Mary pops up in the names list 4 times and I want to be able to take the test scores that are mapped to her and take that average.

The issue is how to compare the duplicate names with the test scores.

Note: I do know that the grades list is longer than the names list, but this was the two lists that was given to me.

Here is what I have done so far

```py
def average_grades(names, grades):
  averages = dict()

  name_counter = 0
  for name in names:
    # if the name is the same 

    if name == names:
    # count the occurence of the name
      name_counter += 1
      print(name_counter)
    # cycle through the grades
      # for grade in grades:
      #   print(grade)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

names = ['Mary', 'Jack', 'Rose', 'Mary', 'Carl', 'Fred', 'Meg', 'Phil', 'Carl', 'Jack', 'Fred', 'Mary', 'Phil', 'Jack', 'Mary', 'Fred', 'Meg']

grades = [80, 88, 53, 80, 64, 61, 75, 80, 91, 82, 68, 76, 95, 58, 89, 51, 81, 78]

score = defaultdict(int)
# this line initializes a default dict with default value = 0

frequency = Counter(names)
# this yields: Counter({'Mary': 4, 'Jack': 3, 'Fred': 3, 'Carl': 2, 'Meg': 2,'Phil': 2, 'Rose': 1})

for name, grade in zip(names, grades):
    score[name] = score.get(name,0)+(grade / frequency[name])
    # here you add the (grade of name / count of name) to each name,
    # score.get(name,0) this line adds a default value 0 if the key does not exist already

print(score)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Mary': 81.25, 'Jack': 76.0, 'Rose': 53.0, 'Carl': 77.5, 'Fred': 60.0, 'Meg': 78.0, 'Phil': 87.5})
```

NOTE: It ignores the last grade, as I have no idea what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate in parallel, find their average and add to the dictionary:

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

names = ['Mary', 'Jack', 'Rose', 'Mary', 'Carl', 'Fred', 'Meg', 'Phil', 'Carl', 'Jack', 'Fred', 'Mary', 'Phil', 'Jack', 'Mary', 'Fred', 'Meg']    
grades = [80, 88, 53, 80, 64, 61, 75, 80, 91, 82, 68, 76, 95, 58, 89, 51, 81, 78]

d = defaultdict(int)
f = lambda x: x[0]
for k, g in groupby(sorted(zip(names, grades), key=f), key=f):
    grp = list(g)
    d[k] = sum(x[1] for x in grp) / len(grp)

print(d)
```